# How to email data using c++

Tags: c++, email, dll, email-attachments

How can i send a file to an specified email using c++?
Note : There are a lots of code in the internet that they needs some special windows dll installed on the user computer to be run, but i want a code that don't need to any extra dll except windows dll to be run on the user computer.

Comment: C++ has no built-in APIs as such.  If you want to get low-level, you can code to the POP3 interface directly with sockets, assuming your mail server supports that.

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C++" itself does not have an API for sending mail. Windows has the "MAPI" API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296721(VS.85).aspx

But if you are trying to avoid dependencies, your minimalist option is going to be to open a connection to an SMTP server (ip.add.re.ss port 25) and hand the mail to it. A minimalistic "send mail" program structure is something like this:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <string>  
using std::string;

static void InitializeWinSock()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to initialize WinSock", "Initialization Error", MBICON_ERROR | MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
}

SOCKET openSocketToServer(const std::string& addr, int port)
{
    // open socket ...
}

#define MAIL_SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define MAIL_SERVER_PORT 25

void sendMail(const string& mailTo, const string& mailFrom, const string& subject, const string& body)
{
    InitializeWinSock();

    SOCKET servSock = openSocketToServer(MAIL_SERVER_IP, MAIL_SERVER_PORT);

    sendToSock(servSock, "HELO sender", "");
    sendToSock(servSock, "MAIL FROM: ", mailFrom.c_str());
    sendToSock(servSock, "RCPT TO: ", mailTo.c_str());
    sendToSock(servSock, "DATA", "");
    sendToSock(servSock, "From: ", mailFrom.c_str());
    sendToSock(servSock, "To: ", mailTo.c_str());
    sendToSock(servSock, "Subject: ", subject);
    sendToSock(servSock, "", ""); // blank line.
    sendToSock(servSock, body.c_str(), "");
    sendToSock(servSock, ".", "");
    sendToSock(servSock, "quit", "");
}
```